# Google's crazy ID and class naming conventions

Tags: css, gmail

I was just playing around with Firebug and editing Gmail's CSS file, and I wanted to edit a button, but the div ID for that button was `:rj`. I am fairly certain that CSS does not allow colons <strike>in</strike> —and especially starting as—ID and class names. So my guess is this is some advanced trickery. I'm not sure if it's consistent like this for each user, but FWIW, the ID was for the "Search Mail" button at the top of the page.

Does anyone know what they are doing and how they are doing it?

Comment: The HTML standard allows colons in id values but the first character of an id must be a letter.

Comment: A better question perhaps is *why* are they doing it? After all, Google is renowned for their clean and standards-compliant code (not just HTML, but I've heard excellent things about their C++), so there must be a good reason why they are disregarding the standard.

Comment: Chances are that all those crazy names are generated by a tool and not what developers actually work with. Google is also renowned for optimization, and shaving a bytes off something downloaded by millions can give real savings.

Comment: They may have also chosen those names to make it difficult for the average developer to access those elements to prevent automation.  For instance, `document.getElementById(":ri")` returns no results, and using the XPATH code here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_XPath, also returns no results when calling `evaluateXPath(document, '//div[contains(@id, concat(":","ri") )]')` or any other selector the attributes of those elements.

Answer (score 6):

IDs used to be quite strict on what was allowed, not so much for classes. HTML5, however, has lessened a lot of the restrictions on what could be ID values.

Here's an article on the what's allowed for IDs and classes in HTML5: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

It's enough to make your head hurt.

EDIT:

To address more of your question about why Google is using a seemingly random ID, I'm sure the IDs and classes they are using make perfect sense to their programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Google only owns one browser so if they want to create a web app that is cross browser compatible like firefox they must follow the same standards and rules as every other web developer.  That said most modern browsers are pretty lenient when it comes to parsing html so while your example is not correct HTML and probably wouldn't validate there would be no visible negative effects.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something along the same lines, but I couldn't find a reason to justify it. Why would they willingly make something potentially browser-incompatible? There has to be a worthwhile trade-off.